# How to encode HDR10+(or Dolby vision) videos to HDR video? (In FFmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg

I downloaded HDR10+(or Dolby vision) videos from YouTube.

Now I want to check the quality difference.

Although I don't have enough good HW display monitor,

I want to convert HDR10+(Dolby vision) video --> to HDR video.
(I heard that Dolby vision is better colors than HDR video.)

Can you share the command?
Thanks in advance.

I searched some ffmpeg command, and I found some command that converts HDR video to SDR video.
But there is no ffmpeg command HDR10+ video to HDR video.

Comment: I would like to do the same. The challenge is that HDR10+ has dynamic metadata (varies across scenes). HDR10 metadata is static, so the conversion process would have to decide what information to keep, and what to loose.